# Display specific length of div element pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I would like to know how to display specific length of an item by pagination.
with the element code below shows 20 items of div elements.

```
<div class="group-of-element">
<div class="items">item1</div>
<div class="items">item2</div>
<div class="items">item3</div>
<div class="items">item4</div>
<div class="items">item5</div>
<div class="items">item6</div>
<div class="items">item7</div>
<div class="items">item8</div>
<div class="items">item9</div>
<div class="items">item10</div>
<div class="items">item12</div>
<div class="items">item13</div>
<div class="items">item14</div>
<div class="items">item15</div>
<div class="items">item16</div>
<div class="items">item17</div>
<div class="items">item18</div>
<div class="items">item19</div>
<div class="items">item20</div>
</div>
```

As a result It would be something like this

[image]

The first 9 of div items would be displayed and when the button "Display Next 9 items" would be clicked it would display the next set of 9 items. And also when the "Display all items" would be clicked, all results should be displayed.

*Updated Also all the old items would need to hide when the "next 9 items" should be clicked

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `:not(:visible)` and `:lt(9)`;

`:not(:visible)` will select elements that are not visible.

`:lt(9)` will select the first 9 items.

```
$(".next").click(function() {
  $(".group-of-element .items:not(:visible):lt(9)").show();
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".next").click(function() {
  var showele = $(".group-of-element .items:not(:visible):lt(9)");
  $(".group-of-element .items").hide();
  showele.show();
})

$(".all").click(function() {
  $(".group-of-element .items").show();
})
```

```css
.items {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-of-element">
  <div class="items">item1</div>
  <div class="items">item2</div>
  <div class="items">item3</div>
  <div class="items">item4</div>
  <div class="items">item5</div>
  <div class="items">item6</div>
  <div class="items">item7</div>
  <div class="items">item8</div>
  <div class="items">item9</div>
  <div class="items">item10</div>
  <div class="items">item12</div>
  <div class="items">item13</div>
  <div class="items">item14</div>
  <div class="items">item15</div>
  <div class="items">item16</div>
  <div class="items">item17</div>
  <div class="items">item18</div>
  <div class="items">item19</div>
  <div class="items">item20</div>
</div>
<button class="next">show next 9</botton><button class="all">all</botton>
```

Comment: This works well but I need also to hide the older 9 items when the button "next 9 items" is clicked. It should be a maximum of 9 items per clicked :)

Comment: @Jon try check the demo now

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a track of the shown items, follow this approach

```
document.querySelector( "#next" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   $( ".group-of-element .items" ).hide().filter( i => i >= lastValue && i <= lastValue + numberOfItems - 1 ).show();
   lastValue = lastValue + numberOfItems > totalItems ? totalItems - 1 :  lastValue + numberOfItems;
});

document.querySelector( "#prev" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   console.log(lastValue);
   $( ".group-of-element .items" ).hide().filter( i => i <= lastValue && i >= lastValue - numberOfItems + 1 ).show();
   lastValue = lastValue - numberOfItems < 0 ? 0 :  lastValue - numberOfItems;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var numberOfItems = 9;
var lastValue = 8;
var totalItems = $( ".group-of-element .items" ).length;

$( ".group-of-element .items" ).filter( i => i >= numberOfItems ).hide();

document.querySelector( "#next" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   $( ".group-of-element .items" ).hide().filter( i => i >= lastValue && i <= lastValue + numberOfItems - 1 ).show();
   lastValue = lastValue + numberOfItems > totalItems ? totalItems - 1 :  lastValue + numberOfItems;
});


document.querySelector( "#prev" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   console.log(lastValue);
   $( ".group-of-element .items" ).hide().filter( i => i <= lastValue && i >= lastValue - numberOfItems + 1 ).show();
   lastValue = lastValue - numberOfItems < 0 ? 0 :  lastValue - numberOfItems;
});
```

```css
.items {
  background-color: #0cf;
  width: 32%;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group-of-element">
  <div class="items">item1</div>
  <div class="items">item2</div>
  <div class="items">item3</div>
  <div class="items">item4</div>
  <div class="items">item5</div>
  <div class="items">item6</div>
  <div class="items">item7</div>
  <div class="items">item8</div>
  <div class="items">item9</div>
  <div class="items">item10</div>
  <div class="items">item12</div>
  <div class="items">item13</div>
  <div class="items">item14</div>
  <div class="items">item15</div>
  <div class="items">item16</div>
  <div class="items">item17</div>
  <div class="items">item18</div>
  <div class="items">item19</div>
  <div class="items">item20</div>
</div>
<button id="next">Next</button><button id="prev">prev</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link for client-side paging, include Jquery pagination.js

[Code for Pagination](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/230996/Client-side-paging-with-jQuery)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, I will take care next time.